# TypeError when chaining exception from a warning

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I am trying to catch a warning that is raised as an error by applying the `'error'` filter of `warnings.simplefilter`.  A minimum working example is given below:

```
>>> import warnings
>>> warnings.simplefilter('error')
>>> try:
...     warnings.warn('test')
... except UserWarning:
...     raise ValueError
...
ValueError:
```

This works fine, but if I want to chain this so that the traceback from the warning is included, I get the following `TypeError`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> try:
...     warnings.warn('test')
... except UserWarning:
...     raise ValueError from sys.exc_info()[2]
...
TypeError: exception causes must derive from BaseException
```

It seems that even though I am raising a class derived from `BaseException` (i.e. the `ValueError`), the information from the traceback from the `UserWarning` seems to be tricking Python into thinking I am still raising the `UserWarning`.

Is this the expected behavior?  If so, is there a good workaround?

I am on Python 3.4.3.

Comment: By all rights I should delete this question because it was a simple mistake on my part mixing up documentation for two different things; however, the title of the question is general enough, and the answer is good enough that it warrants keeping this around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the **traceback object** as the exception:

```
raise ValueError from sys.exc_info()[2]
```

[`sys.exc_info()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) returns a tuple of `(ExceptionType, exception_instance, traceback)`; you'd want index 1 here (remember Python counts indices from `0`!):

```
raise ValueError from sys.exc_info()[1]
```

Much better, capture the exception instance in a variable directly:

```
try:
    warnings.warn('test')
except UserWarning as warning:
    raise ValueError from warning
```

That way you don't have to count out tuple indices.

When you set the warnings filter to `'error'`, the exceptions are subclasses of the [`Warning` exception class](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#Warning), which inherits from `Exception`, see the [*Exception Hierachy* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#exception-hierarchy).

Comment: Thanks. I was convoluting `raise ... from ...` with `raise Exception().with_traceback(...)`.  My actual use case is within a the `__exit__` method of a context manager, so I actually am given `exc_type`, `exc_value`, and `traceback` which is why I presented my example using `sys.exc_info()`.  I was doing `raise Exc from traceback`, but it looks like I should do `raise Exc from exc_value`.

Comment: @SethMMorton: the `Exception.with_traceback()` method doesn't set the `__cause__` attribute. If you don't handle the exception you'd get *only* the new exception printed, while with a `__cause__` attribute you get both, separated by `The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception`.

Comment: Thanks .  For future readers, the above comment did not come out of left field... I had asked about `with_traceback` versus `raise .. from ..` then deleted the question.